# CapabilityClient returns null

Tags: android, wear-os

Wearable.getCapabilityClient always returns null when search for a capability. Even though I have followed the developer guidelines and wear.xml is placed in the correct location, it might not be finding it correctly.

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html

```
 AsyncTask.execute(() -> {
        CapabilityInfo capabilityInfo;

            capabilityInfo = Tasks.await(
                    Wearable.getCapabilityClient(getBaseContext()).getCapability("setqueue", CapabilityClient.FILTER_REACHABLE));
//Returns no nodes
    });
```

Structure for wear.xml
Mobile -> Res -> Values -> wear.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string-array name="android_wear_capabilities">
    <item>setqueue</item>
</string-array>
```

I've no idea why it won't find the capability, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
   private void showNodes() {

    Task<CapabilityInfo> capabilitiesTask =
            Wearable.getCapabilityClient(this)
                    .getCapability(Keys.APP_CAPABILITY, CapabilityClient.FILTER_REACHABLE);

    capabilitiesTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<CapabilityInfo>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(CapabilityInfo capabilityInfo) {

            for (Node node : capabilityInfo.getNodes()) {

                if (node.isNearby()) {

                    //Do something
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What's supposed to go in Keys.APP_CAPABILITY?

Comment: It’s the same value of capability of xml, I just put it on a static string.

Comment: Does this contain a fix, or jut a slightly different api usage?